# How to compare value counts of two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am loading multiple csv's into two dataframes df1,df2 and first check the value counts of a column on both dataframes, I could do it easily
Sample code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{"location":"Location 1"}, {"location":"Location 1"},{"location":"Location 2"},{"location":"Location 1"},{"location":"Location 1"},{"location":"Location 1"},{"location":"Location 1"}, {"location":"Location 2"},{"location":"Location 2"},{"location":"Location 2"}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{"location":"Location 1"}, {"location":"Location 1"},{"location":"Location 2"},{"location":"Location 1"},{"location":"Location 1"},{"location":"Location 2"},{"location":"Location 2"}, {"location":"Location 2"},{"location":"Location 2"},{"location":"Location 2"}])

print(df1['location'].value_counts())
```

this results in

```
Location1     644668      
Location2     616490      
Location3     283440      
print(df2['location'].value_counts())

Location1    640500
Location2    500000
Location3    100000
```

Now what I need to do is compare df2-Location1 count with df1-Location1 count and difference between them should be +-10% ie if df1-df2 is greater than 10% of df1 or less than 10% of df1 then save Location1 to a new list or df or anything, this would continue till all Locations are compared. I tried looping and some other things but didnt get the results.
Final result

```
Location2.  500000
Location3   100000
```

Comment: This isn't very clear. Will you please provide code to create a sample dataframe that's similar to your data?

Comment: What *df2-Locations is greater or less than 10%...* mean, are you just dont want the exact 10%?

Comment: @yeyosef made some edits to the question, if df1-df2 is greater or less than 10% of df1 then save to list or new df. Trying to catch outliers.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your series based on the conditions you described. This will output the counts from Location2 which are outside the 10% threshold.

```
loc1 = df1['location'].value_counts()
loc2 = df2['location'].value_counts()

loc2[abs(loc2-loc1) > (loc1 * .1)]
```

It assumes the same locations exist in both dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([{"location":"Location 1", "value": 100},{"location":"Location 2", "value": 100},{"location":"Location 3", "value": 100}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{"location":"Location 1", "value": 110},{"location":"Location 2", "value": 80},{"location":"Location 3", "value": 105}])


df_new = df1.merge(right=df2, on="location")
df_new["bool"] = False

df_new["bool"] = df_new.apply(lambda row: abs(row.value_x - row.value_y) / row.value_x >= 0.1, axis=1)

print(df_new)

df_new = df_new[df_new["bool"] == True]

print(df_new.drop("bool", axis=1))
```

Output:

```
0  Location 1      100      110   True
1  Location 2      100       80   True
2  Location 3      100      105  False
     location  value_x  value_y
0  Location 1      100      110
1  Location 2      100       80
```

Comment: On df1 in 'location' column the Location 1's count is 644668, location 2 count is 640500, I need to count the number of times each record shows up so df1[location].value_counts. So your solution does work unfortunately