# pandas value_counts(): directly compare two instances

Tags: python, pandas

I have done `.value_counts()` on two dataFrames (similar column) and would like to compare the two.
I also tried with converting the resulting Series to dataframes (`.to_frame('counts')` as suggested in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71488764/how-to-compare-value-counts-of-two-dataframes)), but it doesn't help.

```
first = df1['company'].value_counts()
second = df2['company'].value_counts()
```

I tried to merge but I think the main problem is that I dont have the company name as a column but its the index (?). Is there a way to resolve it or to use a different way to get the comparison?

**GOAL:** The end goal is to be able to see which companies occur more in df2 than in df1, and the value_counts() themselves (or the difference between them).

Comment: `dict(df['a'].value_counts())` gives you a dictionary object with key as 'company' value and value as the frequency of occurrence. You can then use dictionary comparison between 'first' and 'second'

Comment: Union indexes of the value_counts results, then reindex each result and compare.  If you provide same data in the question, we could provide you an solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) ability to `subtract` as follows

```
import collections
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'company':['A','A','A','B','B','C','Y']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'company':['A','B','B','C','C','C','Z']})
c1 = collections.Counter(df1['company'])
c2 = collections.Counter(df2['company'])
c1.subtract(c2)
print(c1)
```

gives output

```
Counter({'A': 2, 'Y': 1, 'B': 0, 'Z': -1, 'C': -2})
```

Explanation: where value is positive means more instances are in `df1`, where value is zero then number is equal, where value is negative means more instances are in `df2`.

Answer (score 0):

Use from this code

```py
df2['x'] = '2'
df1['x'] = '1'
df = pd.concat([df1[['company', 'x']], df2[['company', 'x']]])
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['company'], columns=['x'], aggfunc={'values': 'sum'}).reset_index()
```

Now filter on df for related data